# Java "FileNotFoundException" when feeding arguments to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception, args

I am trying to run a Java program by feeding `args`to Eclipse. This is the part of the code that raises the error:

```
//Store the occupancy matrix in a bitmap image
    new BMP().saveBMP(args[2],occupancy);
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Gian\AIprojects\Homework1\Map.bmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

I am feeding the arguments through `Run -> Run Configurations..` and then on the `Arguments` tab. This is a screenshot of the tab (second argument is the one which is raising the error):

[image]

And this is what the BMP class is doing:

```
public void saveBMP(String filename, int [][] rgbValues){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));

            bytes = new byte[54 + 3*rgbValues.length*rgbValues[0].length + getPadding(rgbValues[0].length)*rgbValues.length];

            saveFileHeader();
            saveInfoHeader(rgbValues.length, rgbValues[0].length);
            saveRgbQuad();
            saveBitmapData(rgbValues);

            fos.write(bytes);

            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
}
```

I should also mention that in the Arguments tab I tried not to give the path, but just the filename "Map.bmp", but it is raising the same error. Does anybody know where's the problem? Thanks

EDIT: This is the Main (there is no args[0], they start from args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpS3N.png)):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception{

        //Input file must be specified in args[1]
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[1])));

        int v = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        // int v = 0;
        int m = (int) pow(2,v);
        System.out.println("M: " + m);

        //Read from the file and set the grid dimensions
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
        int maxX = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())*m;
        int maxY = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())*m;
        System.out.println("maxX: " + maxX + " maxY: " + maxY);

        //Store the matrix of integers that will be written in the .bmp file
        //and initialize it with white cells
        int[][] occupancy = new int[maxX][maxY];
        for(int i=0; i<maxX; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<maxY; j++)
                occupancy[i][j] = 16777215;

        //Read from the file the start and the goal position
        //and store them in the occupancy matrix
        tokens = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
        XYLocation robot = new XYLocation(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())*m,Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())*m);
        System.out.println("Robot");
        System.out.println("X: " + robot.getXCoOrdinate() + " Y: " + robot.getYCoOrdinate());
        occupancy[robot.getYCoOrdinate()][robot.getXCoOrdinate()] = 255;
        tokens = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
        XYLocation finish = new XYLocation(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())*m,Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())*m);
        System.out.println("Goal");
        System.out.println("X: " + finish.getXCoOrdinate() + " Y: " + finish.getYCoOrdinate());
        occupancy[finish.getYCoOrdinate()][finish.getXCoOrdinate()] = 65280;

        //Build the environment
        Environment init = new Environment(robot);
        Environment.setFinish(finish);
        int numWalls = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        for(int i=0; i < numWalls; i++) {
            tokens = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
            XYLocation temp = new XYLocation(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())*m,Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())*m);
            for(int x=0; x < m; x++)
                for(int y=0; y < m; y++) {
                    int newX = temp.getXCoOrdinate()+x;
                    int newY = temp.getYCoOrdinate()+y;
                    Environment.addWall(new XYLocation(newX,newY));
                    occupancy[newY][newX] = 0x000000;
            }
        }

    //Store the occupancy matrix in a bitmap image
        new BMP().saveBMP(args[2],occupancy);
        // new BMP().saveBMP("Map.bmp",occupancy);

      //Use AIMA framework to solve the problem
        Problem problem = new Problem(init, RobotFunctionFactory.getActionsFunction(),
                RobotFunctionFactory.getResultFunction(), new RobotGoalTest());

        RobotWithAStarSearch(problem, robot, occupancy);
        RobotWithDepthFirstSearch(problem, robot, occupancy);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with C:/Users/Gian/AIprojects/Homework1/Map.bmp

If you want to use "\" you have to write it twice because java treats "\" as escape characters in strings.

So either use

```
C:/Users/Gian/AIprojects/Homework1/Map.bmp
```

or

```
C:\\Users\\Gian\\AIprojects\\Homework1\\Map.bmp
```

EDIT

Moreover you call BMP with the param args[2] which is 0. Maybe you sould use args[1]

EDIT2

I see you have put the main.
At the beginning it reads from args[1] which is your file that does not exists, for this it creates an exception, then it writes to args[2] and uses args[3] for other.

So why dont you add an additional argument at the beginning in you eclipse configuration ?

Comment: I tried both "/" and "\\" but I keep getting the error.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is that BMP should create a new FileOutputStream file. Why should it give a FileNotFoundException if it is meant to create it itself?

Comment: You call BMP.saveBMP with the param args[2] which is 0 as of you args list. Maybe you sould use args[1]

Comment: The matter if FileNotFound is that your program cannot find the entire path, not only the file by itself

Comment: I think the code was meant to be run from terminal. So args[0] would be the name of the program. Is that correct? Then, how can I tell Eclipse that args[0] should be skipped?

Comment: are you completely sure this path exists ? C:\Users\Gian\AIprojects\Homework1\Map.bmp

Then
args[0] is the first argument you give to the program
args[2] is the third which is 0

Comment: Yes, the path exists. The file "Map.bmp" does not exist as I want the BMP class to create it. I think the problem is with the args[0] which is missing in the Main...

Comment: I see you have put the main.

Comment: Ok, solved it. The error was the args[0] missing in the code. Basically whoever wrote that part of the main started from args[1] instead of args[0]. Just solved it by lowering all args by one unit: args[1] --> args[0], args[2] --> args[1] and so on... thanks for the help though!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it. Then what first argument would you suggest to add in the configuration? It shouldn't matter, right? So anything in theory would be fine...

Comment: Yes, whatever you like to put there :) Otherwise you need to change the code which is also a good thing :).